# Access control within datatemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

This is XAML:

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Temp">                        
            <DockPanel Width="Auto" Background="White" LastChildFill="False">
                <TextBox Name="txtBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}, Path=Content}" Height="20" Width="100"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <RadioButton Content="Option1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="16" Width="112" Click="RadioButton_Click" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl  ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource Temp}" Content="1"/>
    </Grid>
```

This is codebehind:

```cs
private void RadioButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     StackPanel sp = ((RadioButton)sender).Parent as StackPanel;
     DockPanel dp = sp.Parent as DockPanel;
     TextBox txtbox = dp.FindName("txtBox") as TextBox;

     MessageBox.Show(txtbox.Text);
}
```

Is there a more simple way to access the textbox? 
(As I know I can't get Parent of parent e.g. Parent.Parent...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not that complex!

However, you could simplify it by using [Linq-to-VisualTree](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/):

```cs
private void RadioButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     RadioButton rb = sender as RadioButton;
     TextBox txtbox= rb.Ancestors<DockPanel>().First().Elements<TextBox>().First() as TextBox;
     MessageBox.Show(txtbox.Text);
}
```

The Linq query above finds the first `DockPanel` ancestor of your `RadioButton` (i.e. the `Parent.Parent` that you wanted!), then finds the first `TextBox` child of the `DockPanel`.

However, I typically use Linq-to-VisualTree in cases where the query is more complex. I thin your approach is OK really!

Answer (score 0):

Among other things you can add a reference to it in the RadioButton.Tag:

```
<RadioButton Content="Option1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="16" Width="112"
        Click="RadioButton_Click" Tag="{x:Reference txtBox}" />
```

```cs
private void RadioButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = (sender as FrameworkElement).Tag as TextBox;
    //...
}
```